# How to install wordpress inside subdirectory of Google cloud bitnami wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, bitnami

I have a vm of bitnami wordpress running on google cloud. I want to install another wordpress instance as a subdirectory, so I can access it via [www.domainName.com/blog](http://www.domainName.com/blog).

I see there is a [wordpress multisite with bitnami](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/bitnami-launchpad/wordpress-multisite), but I am not sure if that is necessary, or how I would go about migrating my current bitnami vm to a multisite version.

Comment: You can install a separate installation of WordPress in a subdirectory without affecting the primary WordPress installation provided you do not modify the parent directory and you create a new database to store the new site.

Comment: Following John's words, I would like to add that bitnami wordpress includes apache web server, which you can configure to direct the /blog path to the desired subdirectory.

Comment: @xirehat Looks like my configuration uses nginx instead of apache. I guess I am just not sure where the subdirectory should live in the file folder set up of bitnami and also how to point nginx to go there